# "Job" scheduling with skill restrictions

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

I was given this real life problem and was asked if there would be a way to optimize this, I realize that this is akin to a job scheduling problem, but I can't seem to grasp how to make it work with the restrictions:

Given:

A list of jobs J = { j<sub>1</sub>, j<sub>2</sub>, ..., j<sub>n</sub> } 1 $\le$ n where each job will have a list of operations O = { o<sub>1</sub>, o<sub>2</sub>, ..., o<sub>n</sub> } 1 $\le$ n and each operation will have a skill requirement s, a time to complete t, and a list of required tools RT = { rt<sub>1</sub>, rt<sub>2</sub>, ..., rt<sub>n</sub> } 1 $\le$ n, RT $\subset$ Tools = { t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>, ..., t<sub>n</sub> }. A job is only considered completable if all operations are completable on the same day. An operation is completable if a worker with the correct skill, tools, and time available can be assigned to the operation.

A list of workers W = { w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub>, ..., w<sub>n</sub> } 1 $\le$ n where each worker has a skill s, a list of owned tools OT = { ot<sub>1</sub>, ot<sub>2</sub>, ..., ot<sub>n</sub> } 1 $\le$ n OT $\subset$ Tools = { t<sub>1</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>, ..., t<sub>n</sub> }, and a fixed 8 hours of time available.

Output:

A list of workers to assigned operations in a day ( a schedule ) with the minimum total time wasted ( defined as the total time not spent on an operation for all workers ).

---

I've tried this from a greedy standpoint so far, but every metric I've considered doesn't seem to guarantee minimum time wasted.

Note: This was a problem I tried my best to translate into a more rigidly defined problem, please let me know if I can further clarify this.

Comment: You could always try Integer Linear Programming if you're stuck.  It's the big hammer.